Friedmann Equation and a contracting universe
Consider a universe with a nonzero curvature and matter.
One can write the Friedmann Equation in this universe as such:
$$\frac{H(t)^2}{H_0^2} = \frac{\Omega_0}{a^3}+\frac{1-\Omega_0}{a^2}$$
Where $H(t)$ is the Hubble parameter, $\Omega_0$ is the density parameter for matter (since it is the only component in the universe aside curvature, I will ignore the subscript) and $a$ is scale factor.
Now consider a universe where $\Omega_0$ is greater than 1 (positive curvature), leading in a negative term of $\frac{1-\Omega_0}{a^2}$. It is obvious that the universe will expand first, then come to a halt when $H(t) = 0$.
However, when $H(t)$ turns negative, LHS of the equation is again positive, which is no difference from the expanding scenario. Thus I conclude this universe will expand forever, however this universe will meet its end in the Big Crunch. Which means the universe will first expand until it reach a maximum of scale factor, then contract until everything crash together.
Where did I made a mistake?

@paulina, I conclude that the universe will expand forever, not contract. That is why I am asking where did I made a mistake.

The first Friedmann equation says nothing about the sign of $H$. During expansion, it says how fast the universe is expanding. During contraction, it says how rapidly the universe is contracting. Think of it like a conservation-of-energy expression in classical mechanics. If you know a particle's conserved energy (analogous to $1-\Omega_0$) and position (analogous to $a$), that tells you the particle's speed (analogous to $|aH|$) but not the direction of its velocity (analogous to $aH$).

So how did cosmologist find that the universe is contracting, by using the fluid equation?

At the point where $H=0$ (so $\dot a=0$), you can use the second Friedmann equation to show that $\ddot a<0$. Then you know the sign of $\dot a$ (and hence $H$) is changing from positive to negative, and so it must be negative thereafter.

Alternatively, you can simply integrate the second Friedmann equation from the outset. The analogy with classical particle mechanics is that the first Friedmann equation is like $E=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{x}}^2+m\phi(\vec x)$, while the second Friedmann equation is like $\ddot{\vec{x}} = -\nabla\phi(\vec x)$. The first is convenient, but all you need in principle is the second.
